# Could charm, bottom, and even top matter form under the right circumstances?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, states-of-matter, quark-gluon-plasma

Strange matter forms because [turning some of the down quarks into strange quarks unlocks lower energy levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_matter), and this can lower the system's overall energy at high densities. If the density was pushed higher and higher, could this process repeat for charm, bottom, and top quarks? I'm not suggesting this could happen outside the hypothetical realm--anything that could create the density required for this to happen would probably collapse into a black hole.

Comment: In "principle", yes--what is your concern?

Comment: It seems to me that your answer depends strongly on the conditions under which strange matter could form. Remember that “never” remains a possibility for long-lived strange matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you google "strange matter in cosmological models" , you will see a number of references for papers calculating this with various models. From the latest:

> In this paper, we have examined the Kantowski–Sachs space-time in the presence of strange quark matter with the appearance and non-appearance of strings in f(R) gravity. Here, R is the Ricci scalar of the space-time. Exact solutions of the field equations are obtained by considering the following conditions (i) hybrid scale factor, (ii) the proportionality of shear scalar (σ) with expansion scalar (θ) and (iii) power-law between the scalar-on function F(R) and average scale factor a(t). We have investigated some physical and geometrical properties of the models, and their behavior is thoroughly studied with the help of graphical representation

Highly technical calculations allow the answer to be "yes" it could exist in the timeline of the present [cosmological model.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) A density graph can be seen [here .](https://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/%7Egamk/TUM_Lectures/Lecture4.pdf)